# PHP Paypal IPN - Database updates in sandbox, but not when live

Tags: php, mysql, paypal-ipn

Ok so I'm using http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html for my IPN system.  Here is what I have:

Button Code:

Note: $dream_id is in my database and is collected through dynamically creating web content.  The value would show up as something like "2" when you look at the source code.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="2HGLK2WGELUNG">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $dream_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.dreamsurreal.com/ipn.php">
    <input type="image" src="images/donatebutton.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

ipnlistener.php

```
<?php
/**
* PayPal IPN Listener
*
* A class to listen for and handle Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) from
* the PayPal server.
*
* https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
*
* @package PHP-PayPal-IPN
* @author Micah Carrick
* @copyright (c) 2012 - Micah Carrick
* @version 2.1.0
*/
    class IpnListener {

/**
* If true, the recommended cURL PHP library is used to send the post back
* to PayPal. If false then fsockopen() is used. Default true.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $use_curl = true;

/**
* If true, explicitly sets cURL to use SSL version 3. Use this if cURL
* is compiled with GnuTLS SSL.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $force_ssl_v3 = true;

/**
* If true, cURL will use the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow any
* "Location: ..." headers in the response.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $follow_location = false;

/**
* If true, an SSL secure connection (port 443) is used for the post back
* as recommended by PayPal. If false, a standard HTTP (port 80) connection
* is used. Default true.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $use_ssl = true;

/**
* If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
* post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $use_sandbox = false;

/**
* The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
* before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
*
* @var int
*/
    public $timeout = 30;

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';

/**
* Post Back Using cURL
*
* Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
* the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
* exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
* and post_uri properties on success.
*
* @param string The post data as a URL encoded string
*/
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

    if ($this->use_ssl) {
        $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $this->post_uri = $uri;
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $this->post_uri = $uri;
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,
    dirname(__FILE__)."/cert/api_cert_chain.crt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        }

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

/**
* Post Back Using fsockopen()
*
* Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
* the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
* exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
* and post_uri properties on success.
*
* @param string The post data as a URL encoded string
*/
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'http://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) {
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) {
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024);
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return self::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

/**
* Get POST URI
*
* Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
* be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
* would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

/**
* Get Response
*
* Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
* HTTP headers.
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

/**
* Get Response Status
*
* Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
* if the post back was successful.
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

/**
* Get Text Report
*
* Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
* useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
* this method in your own class to customize the report.
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
       for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

/**
* Process IPN
*
* Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
* method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
* back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and
* throws an exception if there is an error.
*
* @param array
*
* @return boolean
*/
    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) {
            // use raw POST data
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else {
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data);
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

/**
* Require Post Method
*
* Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
* method was not POST.
*/
    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

ipn.php

```
<?php
/*
ipn.php - example code used for the tutorial:

PayPal IPN with PHP
How To Implement an Instant Payment Notification listener script in PHP
http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

(c) 2011 - Micah Carrick
*/

// tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

// intantiate the IPN listener
include('ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

// tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
$listener->use_sandbox = false;

// try to process the IPN POST
try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
}

if ($verified) {

    $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks

    // 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed" 
    if ($_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed') { 
        // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
        exit(0); 
    }

    // 2. Make sure seller email matches your primary account email.
    if ($_POST['receiver_email'] != 'info@dreamsurreal.com') {
        $errmsg .= "'receiver_email' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['receiver_email']."\n";
    }

    // 3. Make sure the amount(s) paid match
    if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != '9.99') {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_gross' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_gross']."\n";
    }

    // 4. Make sure the currency code matches
    if ($_POST['mc_currency'] != 'USD') {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_currency' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_currency']."\n";
    }

    // 5. Ensure the transaction is not a duplicate.
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or exit(0);
    mysql_select_db('dreamsur_real') or exit(0);

    $txn_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txn_id']);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'";
    $r = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$r) {
        error_log(mysql_error());
        exit(0);
    }

    $exists = mysql_result($r, 0);
    mysql_free_result($r);

    if ($exists) {
        $errmsg .= "'txn_id' has already been processed: ".$_POST['txn_id']."\n";
    }

    if (!empty($errmsg)) {

        // manually investigate errors from the fraud checking
        $body = "IPN failed fraud checks: \n$errmsg\n\n";
        $body .= $listener->getTextReport();
        mail('info@dreamsurreal.com', 'IPN Fraud Warning', $body);

    } else {

        // add this order to a table of completed orders
        $payer_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payer_email']);
        $mc_gross = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_gross']);
        $mc_fee = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_fee']);
        $net = $mc_gross - $mc_fee;
        $dream_id = (int)$_POST['custom'];
        $current_donations = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * WHERE `dream_id` = '$dream_id'"));
        $current_donations = $current_donations['current_donations'];
        $net = $net + $current_donations;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (NULL, '$txn_id', '$payer_email', $mc_gross, '$dream_id')";
        mysql_query($sql);

        $sql = "UPDATE `dreams` SET `current_donations` = '$net' WHERE `dream_id` = '$dream_id'";
        mysql_query($sql);

        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
            error_log(mysql_error());
            exit(0);
        }

        // send user an email with a link to their digital download
        $to = filter_var($_POST['payer_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $subject = "Thank you for your donation";
        mail($to, $subject, "Your donation of $" . $mc_gross . " has been donated to Dream Surreal to help make someones dream come true.\n\nThank you very much and bless you\nhttp://www.dreamsurreal.com");
    }

} else {
    // manually investigate the invalid IPN
    mail('info@dreamsurreal.com', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
}
?>
```

I've added some code into the update mysql area so it can update the needed information for me....but for some reason, all of this worked in the sandbox but won't work live...is there something that I'm missing....or should I change my button code from

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
```

To

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
```

Like the example button shows?

Comment: This is actually the same problem that I am experiencing that I just posted the other day here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498654/paypal-ipn-issue-but-works-in-sandbox-fine Glad to know that I'm not the only 1!  If I ever get it sorted out, I'll let you know, but I'm not sure what is wrong either!

Comment: Also, I believe you need to use `_s-xclick` because it is a hosted button on paypal due to the `hosted_button_id` in your code.  Usually, you would use `_xclick` for buttons that aren't hosted on paypal, like subscription buttons, etc.  Furthermore, I could be wrong, but I don't think you need to supply the `notify_url` within the button code itself, as long as you put it within the advanced variables section in Step 3 of the Buttons creation.